# Timer in C# not working as it should

Tags: c#, timer

I have a particular problem while using Timer (System.Timers.Timer). I have checked my code and I can't find what is wrong in my reasoning. I would very much appreciate some insight on this.

**What I want to do**
The program has two infinite loops one inside the other (one called keepRunning and the other one keepTrying). No problem about this, if I press Ctrl-C the loops become finite and the program ends gracefully.

Inside the loop I keep asking the user to press enter. 
Why?

Well, I also have a Timer. This timer calls a function every 3 seconds. If this function gets called 10 times the keepTrying loop *should* become finite and the main program exit this loop. (this is clearly indicated by printing in the console "got out of trying" and "Start trying".

Unless the user press enter. If he presses enter, the timer gets reset, and the number of times the timer has been called also become 0. everything starts again.

Well, it does not work. Somehow, even if the timer elapsed event gets called more than 10 times, it keeps being called and the loop is not exited.

Please take a look at my code. I would appreciate any suggestion to make it work
Thanks

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerExample1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer aTimer;
        private static bool keepRunning = true;
        private static bool keepTrying = true;
        private static int attempts = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //We manage to set the way to finish this program with CTRL+C
            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Cancel = true; //execution continues after the delegate
                keepRunning = false;
                keepTrying = false;
            };

            SetTimer();

            while (keepRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start trying");
                keepTrying = true;

                while (keepTrying)
                {
                    if (attempts > 10) break;

                    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to prevent the timer from firing off...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    //it was pressed so
                    aTimer.Stop();
                    aTimer.Start();
                    attempts = 0;

                }//keep trying


                Console.WriteLine("got out of trying");
            }//keepRunning

            Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...");

            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");

        }
        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                              e.SignalTime);

            attempts++;
            if (attempts > 10) keepTrying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep asking because it's inside the loop and each time you reset the timer which, when expired, will set keepTrying to false which is then set back to true by outer loop and then again and again...

Comment: You never set `keepRunning` to `false`, except when  ctrl-c is pressed. So it never exits the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The outer loop is not supposed to be abandoned except with Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `Console.ReadLine();` is blocking operation. It stops at that place until a user presses the enter key. It does not matter how many times your timer increment attempts and set `keepTrying = false;` its value is not checked in the loop because you are blocked on `ReadLine`. You should change it to using `Console.KeyAvailable` that is not blocking. If there's a key, `Console.ReadKey` it and compare with Enter. Note that if a key is available, you should read it otherwise you will get KeyAvailable all the time until you empty the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found about this when I pressed enter one more time and the rest of the code worked. Thanks again!